# I want to display the total amount of NFTs minted for an NFT project on the webpage using .jsx

Tags: reactjs, variables, jsx, console.log, nft

This is my code for a basic webpage that allows the user to mint using their metamask wallet.  What I want to do is to display the Total amount minted on the screen for the user to see.  For this I'll just say I would want it to be x/4756.  I have the place for me that displays the total minted down below and I have **** where I would like the x/4756 to be at.  My problem is that I cannot seem to get the x to show as the amount minted.  I have it showing up in console.log, but cannot get it to be displayed on the screen.  I searched on the web and tried out things like putting {} around the variable "count" but it keeps saying that the variable I place in the {} is undefined.  Is there a way that I can either place the variable in there and then just type /4756 to have it displayed as x/4756, or even a way to pull it out of the console.log?  Let me know if anyone has any ideas! Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import abi from "./util/WavePortal.json";

const App = () => {
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");

  const contractAddress = "0xbA0d7f21F06C329188580864e06DD6cdb03F1e5d"
  const contractABI = abi.abi;
  
  const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async () => {
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;

      if (!ethereum) {
        console.log("Make sure you have metamask!");
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("We have the ethereum object", ethereum);
      }

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });

      if (accounts.length !== 0) {
        const account = accounts[0];
        console.log("Found an authorized account:", account);
        setCurrentAccount(account);
      } else {
        console.log("No authorized account found")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  /**
  * Implement your connectWallet method here
  */
  const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;

      if (!ethereum) {
        alert("Get MetaMask!");
        return;
      }

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

      console.log("Connected", accounts[0]);
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  const wave = async () => {
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;

      if (ethereum) {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const wavePortalContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

        let count = await wavePortalContract.getTotalWaves();
        console.log("Retrieved total wave count...", count.toNumber());
        let count2 = count.toNumber();
        const waveTxn = await wavePortalContract.wave();
        console.log("Mining...", waveTxn.hash);
        
        await waveTxn.wait();
        console.log("Mined -- ", waveTxn.hash);

        count = await wavePortalContract.getTotalWaves();
        console.log("Retrieved total wave count...", count.toNumber());
      } else {
        console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
  
  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfWalletIsConnected();
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div className="mainContainer">
      <div className="dataContainer">
        <div className="header">
         Welcome to the Project!
        </div>

        <div className="bio">
          This is my first site and I am proud of it.
        </div>
        
        <div className="bio">
          Total Mints: ****
        </div>

        <button className="waveButton" onClick={wave}>
          Mint
        </button>
        
        {/*
        * If there is no currentAccount render this button
        */}
        {!currentAccount && (
          <button className="waveButton" onClick={connectWallet}>
            Connect Wallet
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: What does `getTotalWaves()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use useState hook for count.

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState();
```

after you get count from request set it with setCount

```js
count = await wavePortalContract.getTotalWaves();
setCount(count)
```

Finally just insert count var in JSX.

```js
<div className="bio">
 Total Mints: `${count}`
</div>
```

Hope it helps:)